# One large MySQL database for several clients

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant, multi-tenant

N.B. This is not another "One large DB or several small DBs" question.

Using one large MySQL database for several clients (same structure, etc), with a `user` column to separate the clients, is it possible limit the table access for the user with the matching `user` column`?

I'm not too familiar with Microsoft's SQL Server, but I read something about "multi-tenant data architecture" that seemed to offer this.

Does MySQL have something similar?

Comment: Not natively no, but you can 'relatively easily' emulate it through different databases per client. That approach provides implicit security and scalability.

Comment: @yshavit I know that, but that's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has table-level and column-level privileges, but not row-level privileges.

The closest thing would be to define a VIEW through which a user accesses the table. The view has privilege to access to the base table, and each user has privileges to access the view.

Define the view to restrict access to the current user.

```
mysql> create table base (user varchar(16), x int);
mysql> insert into base values ('root@localhost', 123), ('bill@localhost', 456);
mysql> create view v as select * from base where user = USER() with check option;
mysql> select * from v;
+----------------+------+
| user           | x    |
+----------------+------+
| root@localhost |  123 |
+----------------+------+
```

Comment: Nice answer!  You answered my question and gave me a good workaround!

Comment: Do you mean "define a VIEW for each **table**" instead of "define a VIEW for each **user**"?  It seems the one view `v` will work for all users.

Comment: @Sarke, yes, good call. One view for each table will do. Also, it's not necessarily true that every table needs to be treated this way; some tables may be completely accessible by all users.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against having 1 large DB for all your clients for multiple reasons:

1. I've worked at a startup where the AWS instance for one of our DB just gave away (for no fault of ours). Let's just say that was a hectic day for everyone in the office. If this happens to your ONLY DB, how are you going to ensure customer satisfaction? How are you going to maintain a robust system? There's a saying that at google, a server goes does every 2 seconds. While that may not happen when you're starting off, know that you're not immune from your servers failing. Sharding your DB into multiple instances is a good way of hedging against a major failure.
2. If you have many transactions, your thread pool is always going to get locked up. You don't want this because it's going to increase the amount of time it takes to perform CRUD operations on your database, which in turn is going to effect customer satisfaction.

A better mult-tenant archticture you want to have is:

1. Have 1 master DB for every client (maybe every 2 clients at the beginning), then have slaves for every master DB you have. Now you can perform all your writes on the slaves and perform all your reads off of the master. As long as you keep your DB's in sync, this is the best way to ensure your thread pool maintains availability and quickly performs all the transactions.

Here's a great article titled "[High Availability, Load Balancing, and Replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/high-availability.html)," which will give you a great primer into building a robust multi-tenant system. I would also recommend reading the articles on [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/)

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Interesting, I like your take on "read master, write slave".  Upvote, but sadly it's not the answer to my question.